# Docker with CosmosDB emulator: TimeoutException when trying to communicate with Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to play with Docker, emulator for CosmosDB (Mongo connector) on local environment.
I installed Docker desktop and created the following docker compose file:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  cosmosdb:
    container_name: "azurecosmosemulator"
    hostname: "azurecosmosemulator"
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator'
    environment:
        - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=5
        - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true
        - ENABLE_MONGODB_ENDPOINT=4.0
        - AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=172.22.224.1
    tty: true
    mem_limit: 3GB
    ports:
        - '8081:8081'
        - '10255:10255'
    entrypoint: 
        - /usr/local/bin/cosmos/start.sh
        - EnableMongoDbEndpoint=4.0
        - MongoPort=10255
        - AllowNetworkAccess
        - Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
        - NoFirewall
    command: ["mongod", "--port", "10255"]
    volumes:
        - vol_cosmos:/usr/share/cosmosdbemulator/data
volumes:
  es_data:
    driver: local
  vol_cosmos:
    driver: local
```

Run it with the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p cosmosdb up -d
```

It successfully starts as I see in Docker desktop. Trying to interact with emulator using the following code in .Net Core:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
// connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true"
var database = client.GetDatabase(options.Value.DatabaseName);
var collection = this.database.GetCollection<Person>(containerId);
var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "test",
    LastName = "Name"
};
await collection.InsertOneAsync(person);
```

But got this exception running that code:

> A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using
> CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{
> ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
> AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 },
> OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is {
> ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/localhost:10255" }", EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/localhost:10255", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State:
> "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
> HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
> exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party
> has closed the transport stream.    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
> Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslClientAuthenticationOptions)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost,
> X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols
> enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint
> endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp:
> "2023-08-30T06:20:35.8689000Z", LastUpdateTimestamp:

Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is the connection string correct? looking and the commented one it seems not. Did you followed this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21 ? Isee you are overriding the IP, are you sure it is the correct value? might be better to calculate it https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/95589

Comment: I copy-pasted this connection string from Data Explorer. And yes, I followed the example from learn.microsoft.com.